# Enabled option for useQueries

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to use useQueries like this

```
function App({ users }) {
   const userQueries = useQueries(
     users.map(user => {
       return {
         queryKey: ['user', user.id],
         queryFn: () => fetchUserById(user.id),
       }
     })
   )
 }
```

However, the users variable is being supplied by a useQuery and comes back undefined at first. This causes the error cannot read map of undefined. I want to add enabled like you can for useQuery, but I don't see it anywhere in the documentation. You can do it with a simple useQuery like this:

```
// Get the user
 const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
 
 const userId = user?.id
 
 // Then get the user's projects
 const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
 
 // isIdle will be `true` until `enabled` is true and the query begins to fetch.
 // It will then go to the `isLoading` stage and hopefully the `isSuccess` stage :)
```

essentially I want

```
function App({ users }) {
   const userQueries = useQueries(
     users.map(user => {
       return {
         queryKey: ['user', user.id],
         queryFn: () => fetchUserById(user.id),
         enabled: !!users
       }
     })
   )
 }
```

Comment: What about useEffect? put as dependecy the users array and when populated pass it to a state

Comment: I had the exact same issue. I feel like the ideal syntax would be like this if we were following their other conventions. You would need enabled properties for the useQueries as well as the individual useQuery inside the map...

`
function App({ users }) {
   const userQueries = useQueries(
     users.map(user => {
       return {
         queryKey: ['user', user.id],
         queryFn: () => fetchUserById(user.id),
       }
     }),
     {
        enabled: !!users
     }
   )
 }
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just fallback to an empty array that you pass to useQueries if you have no users:

```
function App({ users }) {
   const userQueries = useQueries(
     users?.map(user => {
       return {
         queryKey: ['user', user.id],
         queryFn: () => fetchUserById(user.id),
       }
     }) ?? []
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

### Update

In React Query v4 the `useQueries` hook has been slightly modified (see: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4#new-api-for-usequeries). Instead of passing the array directly, you need to pass an object with a `query` param:

```js
  const results = useQueries({
    queries: [
        { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: getProjectsByUser, enabled: !!userId },
        { queryKey: ['post', 2], queryFn: getProjectsByUser, enabled: !!userId },
    ]
  })
```

### Original Answer (for React Query 3)

For people landing here from a search: This is now supported:

```js
  const results = useQueries([
    { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: getProjectsByUser, enabled: !!userId },
    { queryKey: ['post', 2], queryFn: getProjectsByUser, enabled: !!userId },
  ])
```

See https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQueries#_top